# Grouping a simple array with php

Tags: php

I wonder if someone can help me. I have an array which I need to group by 'Airport Retailer', 'Seaport Retailer', etc.

```
Array
(
    [World Duty Free Group] => Airport Retailer
    [Duty Free Americas Inc] => Airport Retailer
    [DFASS Distribution] => Airport Retailer
    [Monalisa Int'l SA] => Downtown Retailer
    [DUFRY America 1] => Seaport Retailer
    [Neutral Duty Free Shop] => Border Retailer
    [Saint Honoré] => 
    [SMT PR Duty Free Inc] => Seaport Retailer
    [Aer Rianta International] => Airport Retailer
    [London Supply] => Downtown Retailer
    [Royal Shop Duty Free] => Downtown Retailer
    [Harding Brothers Retail] => Cruise/Ferry Retailers
    [Motta Internacional SA] => Airport Retailer
    [Tortuga Rum Co Ltd] => Downtown Retailer
    [Pama Duty Free] => Seaport Retailer
    [Little Switzerland] => Downtown Retailer
....
)
```

The result should be:

```
Array
(
    [Airport Retailer] => World Duty Free Group
    [Airport Retailer] => Duty Free Americas Inc
    [Airport Retailer] => DFASS Distribution
...
)
```

Comment: You can't have an array with duplicate keys, you'll have to settle for another structure.

Comment: or you can create array for each type, like the structure might be like, 'Array([Airport Retailer]=>Array(World Duty Free Group,Duty Free American INC, DFASS Distrubution)'

Comment: You're probably better off not building the original array that way in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

```
function testFunc($array)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $_index => $_value)
    {
        $result[$_value][] = $_index;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this by looping over your results and add values for the same key.  Here is some dummy-code (in this case the key is the value):

```
$data = array();
foreach ((array)$results as $item => $key) {
  $data[$key][] = $item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it exactly that way, as you would repeat keys in the array (in the example you put, you would have N keys named "[Airport Retailer]".

Yet, you can create an array grouping the items you want:

```
$arr= array();
foreach ($initialArray as $key => $item) {
  if ($item=="[Airport Retailer]") $arr[] = $key;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function processArray( $arr ) {
  $result = Array();

  foreach( $arr as $key => $val ) {
    if( $val === "Airport Retailer" ) {
      $result[] = $key;
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
```

You cannot have duplicate keys, therefore, this is 'just' a list.

For your example set this will result in

```
Array(
  [0] => World Duty Free Group
  [1] => Duty Free Americas Inc
  [2] => DFASS Distribution
...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a multi-dimensional array if ever wanted to insert multiple values into a same key, such as:

```
Array(
  [Airport Retailer] => array (World Duty Free Group,
                               Duty Free Americas Inc,
                               DFASS Distribution),
  [foo] => x,
  [bar] => array(y,w,z)
)
```

I honestly hope that helps, I'd do it like that.